# SVN Repository Questions, helping to edit a friends website

Tags: html, svn, server, repository, hook

One of my friends has a website he wants me to assist him with, me being the good friend that I am means I was happy to oblige, however he wants me to use an SVN, I am currently using tortoiseSVN.

The problem is when I make changes and commit it to the repository, it does not reflect on the website, I don't have access to the server side is there anything I can do from my side to apply changes I committed? some client side hook scripts or something?

Answer (score 3):

Committing to the svn alone does not update the files on the server. Your friend will need to run 'svn update' on the directory on his server.